# Integrating the slideshow plugin into ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, slideshow

How can I integrate the slideshow plugin into the ckeditor?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the third-party [Slideshow plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/slideshow) for CKEditor.

Read how to install additional CKEditor plugins here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins.

Comment: No. I'm sorry. I want add slideshow plugin for ckeditor on drupal 7